# JQuery .each() replacement (for..in)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to replace .each() with for..in loop?

```
$('.my_class').each(function() {
  ...
});
```

Selector  $('.class') is not returning an array of objects, but "just" objects.

You can see this with:

```
console.log($('.my_class'));
```

Considering that this is not an array of objects => it is not possible to iterate through all found objects with for..in loop?

Is .each() the only solution?

Comment: I believe `$('.my_class').get()` returns you an Array

Comment: What do you mean, "just objects"? What do you want to do with a for/in that you can't do with `each`?

Comment: I've just tried it and yes `for` loop works for the `$(...)`, in fact `$(...)` is some **extended** array http://jsfiddle.net/aEwE4/

Comment: If you mean `for .. in` then No, `for .. in` will loop through the properties of an object, not the items in a collection/list, in the case of array, you will get the index of item via the counter variable.

Comment: King: so this is a simple array, not assoc array...

Comment: It's an array-like object

Comment: Why do you want to use a for..in loop and not .each()

Comment: adeneo: I can use each, just was curious if any replacement exists.

Comment: *returns you an Array of native DOM selections I mean - . eg to be able to do `$('.my_class').get(i).innerHTML='...` , or similar. Which is what I think you are asking for.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do it, but .each() seems like the most appropriate, but it all depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Selector `$('.class')` is not returning an array of objects, but "just" objects.

It returns a jQuery object. A [**jQuery object**](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) can be seen as a collection of HTML elements.

As a jQuery object supports the `.length` property and the `[]` accessor, it could be seen as an array of HTML Elements, though it is really not.

> Considering that this is not an array of objects => it is not possible to iterate through all found objects with for..in loop?

Using the `.length` and `[]` directly in the `$('.my_class')`, you can use `for` loops.

[But don't use `for..in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/1850609), as it iterates through the properties of a JavaScript object, not through the indexes of an array.

> Is `.each()` the only solution?

Being a "solution", of course, depends on the problem. But if you are asking about alternatives, if you must use the `for` loop, you could:

```
var elements = $('.my_class'), i, n, element;
for (i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
    element = elements[i];
    // do stuff with element (it is an HTML Element)
}
```

Though, if you really need an array of elements, you can call the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or, better, the [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) function in the jQuery object:

```
// here, elementsArray is really an array of HTML Elements
var elementsArray = $('.my_class').toArray();
```

Comment: In fact we can consider the indices are some special kind of properties (which can't be accessed via the dot `.`, instead we have to use `[]`), we can still use the `for ... in` but we have to check variable `i` (in `for(var i in ...)`) to be sure it is *numeric*, then we can access to the element using `[]` normally. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/aEwE4/2/)

Comment: @KingKing That's right (as you already know :). The thing with `for..in`, and the reason I always point it out, is that is is frequently misunderstood and thus misused. But your demo shows the code of someone who understands that loop's characteristics and uses it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

> Selector $('.class') is not returning an array of objects, but "just" objects.

It actually returns a jQuery object, which is an object with an array-like structure.

As mentioned in the comments, you can get array with the elements using `$('.class').get()`.

Since it's still an array, I wouldn't recommend the for...in loop, which should be used to iterate object properties rather than arrays. Even though it will work, I'll recommend a "normal" for loop e.g.

```
var elements = $('.myclass').get();

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    console.log(elements[i]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ygMa/

Is this what you're asking for?